# phonegap + drupalgap + jquerymobile how to debug?

Tags: android, cordova

Here is a function get the node of a webservice of drupal in ssets\www\modules\node\node.js of the android project. When i click content and try to retrieve a node in the apps in android emulator, there is an error message "node_page_view reference error:nid is not defined", the apps seems can read the node/%, so i want to debug the function, see the alert(node); in the following code. But i re-run the program, there is nothing happen, any ideas?

```
function node_page_view(node) {
    alert(node);
      try {
        if (drupalgap.settings.debug) {
          console.log('node_page_view()');
          console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
        }
        if (node) {
          var build = {
            'theme':'node',
            'node':node, // TODO - is this line of code doing anything?
            'title':{'markup':node.title}, // TODO - this is a core field and should probably by fetched from entity.js
            'content':{'markup':node.content},
          };
          // If the comments are hidden, do nothing.
          if (node.comment == 0) { }
          // If the comments are closed or open, show the comments.
          else if (node.comment == 1 || node.comment == 2) {

            // Build an empty list for the comments
            build.comments = {
              'theme':'jqm_item_list',
              'title':'Comments',
              'items':[],
              'attributes':{'id':'comment_listing_items'},
            };

            // If the comments are open, show the comment form.
            if (node.comment == 2) {
              build.comments_form = {
                'markup':
                  '<h2>Add comment</h2>' +
                    drupalgap_get_form('comment_edit', {'nid':node.nid})
              };
            }
          }

          return build;
        }
        else {
          alert('node_page_view - failed to load node (' + nid + ')');
        }
      }
      catch (error) {
        alert('node_page_view - ' + error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you download the latest version of 7.x-1.x-alpha of DrupalGap, this should be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried weinre?

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

or Medic:

https://github.com/filmaj/medic